# Laravel Mail not sending to Log

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, logging, laravel-mail

I am having some troubles with Laravel 5.8 and sending the Mail into the logs for testing purposes.

Regular log level INFO gets written to the daily log without any trouble.

What am I missing in my current config?

**.ENV file has :**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

**Mail.php**

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
 'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

**Logging.php**

```
 'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['daily'],
        ],
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I tried to add some clarity. Just trying to have the emails outputted into the logs for testing purposes.

Comment: Your code seems correct, did you forget to run `artisan config:cache`?

Comment: The clear config:cache? Sure did, I’m totally stumped

Answer (score 1):

## Laravel :

Basically if you change or add any config, you must need to run `clear:config` or `config:cache` like below:

Run `php artisan config:cache` on terminal of project directory.

Comment: Not sure if it changed, but in Laravel 7 it's `config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/telescope) and it works great. It has a `Mail` page which shows you all rendered emails. No need to send mail to log to debug. [Matt Stauffer](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/introducing-laravel-telescope/) has a detailed go through of Telescope

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel version 7 or greater, the .env file variable has changed:

```
VERSIONS <=6: MAIL_DRIVER=log
VERSIONS >=7: MAIL_MAILER=log
```